# Change input and submit form for scraping task

Tags: python, authentication, input, scrapy, asp.net-identity

I am currently working on a scrapy task to scrape economic calendar data from https://tradingeconomics.com/calendar, but I would like to change the input of startDate and endDate to make it extract data from different dates.

This is what I have written so far:

```
import scrapy
from datetime import datetime
from example.items import CalendarItem
import pytz

class calendarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "calendar"

    def start_requests(self):
        url  = 'https://tradingeconomics.com/calendar'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
        
                                                        
    def parse(self, response):
        item = CalendarItem()
        filename = 'calendar.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

        table = response.xpath('//body//div[@class="container"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@class="col-lg-8 col-md-9"and@role="main"]//div[@class="table-responsive panel panel-default"]')
        # table has length 2, table[1] is the actual table I would like to scrape

       # China & US table records + date info
        rows = table[1].xpath('.//tr[@data-country="china" or @data-country="united states"] | .//thead[@class="table-header"]//tr//th[@colspan="3"]')

        date = rows[0].xpath('.//text()').get().strip()

        for this_row in rows:

            # date
            new_date = this_row.xpath('.//text()').get().strip()
            if len(new_date) and (new_date != date):
                date = new_date

            if not len(new_date):
                # when new_date = ''
                time = this_row.xpath('.//td/span[starts-with(@class,"calendar-date")]/text()').get()
                item['date'] = date
                item['time'] = [time.strip() if time else 'All Day'][0]

                # country
                item['country'] = this_row.xpath('.//td[@class="calendar-item"]//table//tr//td[@class="calendar-iso"]/text()').extract()
              
                #event
                event1 = this_row.xpath('.//td/a[@class="calendar-event"]/text()').get() # usually the main title
                event2 = this_row.xpath('.//td/span[not(@id) and not(@class)]/text()').get() # some has additional information (e.g.:FEB,Q4)
                events = [event1, event2]
                item['event'] = ' '.join(filter(None, events))
             
                yield item
```

And if we run the script for once, it will extract data for ~10days. (say today is 10 March then the scraped data would be 10 March -- 20 March.

However I would like to extract another 20 days' data, so I need data from 20 March -- 10 April.

I noticed we can add input to the website, we can change the date filter:
[change date filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJczg.png)

and the corresponding HTML code is the **startDate** and **endDate** here:

```
<div id="datesDiv" class="collapse">
            <br />
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon hidden-sm hidden-xs">From</span>
                <input type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" value="2020-03-09 17:58" />
                <span class="input-group-addon hidden-sm hidden-xs">Until</span>
                <input type="text" id="endDate" class="form-control" value="2020-03-15 01:58" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="setCustomDates(event);">Submit</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have the feeling that I should change the input and "submit the form" so that the scraped website will have data for desired dates, but I could not figure out how to do this successfully.

I referred to [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login)  and tried this in the **scrapy shell**

```
fetch(scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'startDate':'2020-03-20', 'endDate':'2020-04-10'}))
```

Apparently this is not working... I checked the network under Developer Tools for the website, but I didn't see a **POST** section everytime i change the date. And the FormData only contains pre-defined filters, for example:

[FormData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3dbw.jpg)

corresponds to

[setCalendarRange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Pej.png)

So I am not sure what should I do if I want to add input for the date filter during scraping stage..

Could anyone help?
Thanks a lot!

-- **Update**

Have tried this

```
def start_request(selfself):
    yield Request(url=url,
                  cookies={'te-custom-range-importance' :'2020-03-09|2020-03-26',
                           'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'bkvsst1k4ocgs2v4d0x1cjfa',
                           'TEServer': 'TEIIS3',
                           'TECalendarOffset':'-240',
                           'te_sso_sync_/calendar':'Tue Mar 10 2020 01:23:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'},
                  callback = self.parse)
```

But seems it did not scrape anything from the website and no calendar.html was generated..

Comment: Have you solved yr problem? I don't know how to change countries by POST form data to  "https://sso.tradingeconomics.com/api/UserOptions"

Answer (score 1):

ASP websites do some funny things. Usually it sends a base64 encoded string around in a __VIEWSTATE variable. In this case its actually passing data in through the cookies.

Looking at the submit button it actually doesnt submit the form it executes JS setCustomDates which forces a refresh causing $(document).ready to be called again.

[location.reload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) refreshes the browser just like the refresh button would.

Relevant code to attempt to reverse engineer. Search for a div id="aspnetForm" it contains the hidden form attributes. You can decode __VIEWSTATE using base64 and see if you can't reverse engineer it. Usually at this point I'm tired of looking around in the source and unless its necessary to reverse engineer it will just use Selenium for the sake of getting the project completed in a timely manner.

If you look on down in the JS in document.ready function there is code for parsing the cookies. I think if you can reverse engineer this cookie creation and setup the cookies and __VIEWSTATE variable you will have success.

I know it is possible because in firefox I can edit the request and resend it and it will return the proper data from a GET request.

There's always Selenium also...

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        console.info("/js/calendar.ascx");

        if (!isPostBack) {
            var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -1;  // Difference in minutes between UTC and local time.

            var offsetCookie = GetCalendarCookie("TECalendarOffset");
            if (offsetCookie) {
                offset = offsetCookie;
                console.info("CALENDAR TIMEZONE SET FROM COOKIE TECalendarOffset");
            }

            // Avoid refresh if offset is default (From London)
            if (offset == 0) {
                console.info("CALENDAR USER TIME ZONE IS UTC");
            }
            else if (offsetCookie) {
                // Need to implement a server way to get the cookie
                console.info("CALENDAR SERVED USING COOKIE TECalendarOffset");
            }
            else if ($("#DropDownListTimezone option[value=" + offset + "]").length > 0) {
                setOffset(offset)

            }
        }

        function GetCalendarCookie(name) {
            console.log('READING CALENDAR COOKIE', name);
            var nameEQ = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
            }
            return null;

    function setCustomDates(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
        var endDate = $("#endDate").val();
        //console.log('startDate', startDate, 'endDate', endDate);
        var lifetime = .5 * 24 / 60 / 60; //five minutes in days
        //console.log('lifetime', lifetime);
        // This variable is found above in the JS var CUSTOM_RANGE_COOKIE_NAME = "te-custom-range-importance"; 
        window.TEcreateCookie(CUSTOM_RANGE_COOKIE_NAME, startDate + "|" + endDate, lifetime);
        window.TEeraseCookie(RANGE_COOKIE_NAME);
        location.reload();
    }



Cookie: te-custom-range-importance=2020-03-09|2020-03-26; ASP.NET_SessionId=bkvsst1k4ocgs2v4d0x1cjfa; TEServer=TEIIS3; TECalendarOffset=-240; te_sso_sync_/calendar=Tue Mar 10 2020 01:23:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Yes I have tried the method before, and have tried the code you shared but it does not scrap anything from the website (i.e. output calendar.html file was not generated..). I have updated the description and pasted my code above. Could you help me with that? Perhaps is there anything I missed in the code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Understand that this function is setting a customized date range and reload the page using the newly created cookie, could you advise on where should I add this setCustomDates function? I'm new to JavaScript and web scrapping and not sure where to see the JS file.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without running a JS interpreter (web browser) you can't execute this JS function. Looking at what it does though its just creating a cookie which you should be able to do. You may have to follow the code to see but I imagine it is JS that looks at these cookies and loads in the data.  If possible its always good to reverse engineer so you can do without web browser, but sometimes you must just run the JS interpreter if it takes too long to figure out or is impossible.

Comment: I updated my answer I believe your solution lies in __VIEWSTATE and the hidden variables it is passing around